# Match_phrase is elastic search not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

In my elastic search I have documents which contains a "fieldname" with values "abc" and "abc-def". When I am using match_phrase query for searching documents with fieldname "abc" it is returning me documents with values "abc-def" as well. However when I am querying for "abc-def" it is working fine. My query is as follows:

```
  Get my_index/_search
   {
     "query" : {
           "match_phrase" : {"fieldname" : "abc"}
       }
   }
```

Can someone please help me in understanding the issue?

Comment: It may be because of the standard tokenizer which is applied by default. If you are expecting different results... change the tokenizer to the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) query analyzes the search term based on the analyzer provided for the field (if no analyzer is added then by default [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is used).

**Match phrase query searches for those documents that have all the terms present in the field (from the search term), and the terms must be present in the correct order.**

2. In your case, `"abc-def"` gets tokenized to `"abc"` and `"def"` (because of standard analyzer). Now when you are using match phrase query for `"abc-def"`, this searches for all documents that have both `abc` and `def` in the same order. (therefore you are getting only 1 doc in the result)
3. When searching for `"abc"`, this will search for those documents that have `abc` in the `fieldname` field (since both the document contain `abc`, so both are returned in the result)

*If you want to return only exact matching documents in the result, then you need to change the way the terms are analyzed.*

4. If you have not explicitly defined any mapping then you need to add `.keyword` to the `fieldname` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after the fieldname field).

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index data:**

```
{
    "name":"abc-def"
}
{
    "name":"abc"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "name.keyword": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67394740",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "name": "abc"
        }
      }
    ]
```